# Shorthand method for expressing the limit of something

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

Solving limits takes a lot of steps sometimes, but I feel bad leaving out the limit each time I do something and rewrite "=". Is there a shorthand method for writing the limit?
 $$\lim_{x \to p}f(x) = L$$
That looks nice, but it takes a lot of writing. And series notation isn't any better for me.

Comment: For more options, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972860/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the context? If you're handwriting something for calculus class, I think one clear thing to do (if a bit nonstandard) would be to write something like $$\lim_{x\to p}\begin{cases}
f\left(x\right)\\
=f_{1}\left(x\right)\\
=f_{2}\left(x\right)\\
=x
\end{cases}$$
$$=p$$
Alternatively, if you're doing lots of calculations with the same limit, you could write something like "$\ell$ denotes $\lim_{x\to p}$" and just use $\ell$ everywhere.

In certain more advanced contexts, you might see something like: "As $x\to p$, we have $$\begin{align*}f(x)&=f_1(x)\\&=f_2(x)\\&=17\end{align*}$$But I wouldn't recommend using it yourself, because it's too easy for the limiting process to go unnoticed/forgotten that way.

Comment: I really like all three of your solutions. The context is me handwriting countless solutions for a Calculus II and Analytic Geometry course. Specifically, we are doing a lot of limits and series, and I often get lost when I don't write the limit, or I get sloppy when I rewrite it 5 times in a row. I understand most of what's going on, but I get way too messy on the page.